# missing borders for an html table

Tags: html

I have the following piece of code

```
 <html>
 <head>
<body bgcolor="#BDBDBD">
<div align="center">
<font color="Blue">
<CAPTION><b><u><i>SYSTEM STATUS</i></u></b></caption>
</font>
</br>
</br>

<table BORDER="2" BORDERCOLOR="Black" CELLPADDING="3">

 <colgroup>
 <col span="2" style="background-color:FFA04A">
<col style="background-color:FFA04A">
</colgroup>

<thead>
<tr>
<font color="Blue">
        <th><font color="Blue">System</font></th>
        <th><font color="Blue">Is Alive</font></th>
        </font>
</tr>
</thead>
</font>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

i am getting the output as atable with black borders but the border which seperates column is missing..is anything wrong with the code.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjk5t/)

Comment: Correct your HTML and after that it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/8E75t/

Comment: Maybe you should look up how HTML is done these days. This is awesomely obsolete on modern web. Use CSS.

Comment: This code looks like it's from '90. If you are learning HTML and CSS then then change your sources to something modern.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are beginner ,please review this code

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body bgcolor="#BDBDBD">
    <div align="center">
    <font color="Blue"> <b><u><i>SYSTEM STATUS</i></u></b> </font> </br>
    </br>
    <table BORDER="2" BORDERCOLOR="Black" CELLPADDING="3">
    <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:FFA04A">
    <col style="background-color:FFA04A">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr> <font color="Blue">
        <th><font color="Blue">System</font></th>
        <th><font color="Blue">Is Alive</font></th>
        </font> </tr>
    </thead>
    </font>
    </body>
    </html>
```

DemO:http://jsfiddle.net/26TCe/

Answer (score 0):

See [description of](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp) : "The  tag specifies column properties for each column within a  element."
You'll have to define 3  elements: insert an (empty) `<th/>` between